# .then(function () meaning in excel javascript

Tags: typescript

```
    Excel.run(function (context) {
    var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    var range = sheet.getRange("B2:C5");
    range.load("address");

    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            console.log(`The address of the range B2:C5 is "${range.address}"`);
        });
}).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
```

In above mentioned documentation I can understand most of the code.
But I don't understand this one line.

```
  .then(function ()
```

1. I already googled related keyword.
2. I already checked this ([website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-core-concepts)
3. I know VBA, I don't know javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Office API, as well as many other current APIs, calls return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which is a way to describe asynchronous resources. Promises have a `then` function defined which takes a function to execute when the Promise resolves, aka the async task is finished.

Promises are an alternative to callback functions.

Hopefully that helps to clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has this thing known as `Promise`. Look at these docs for understanding promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

In simple words, promises are proxy objects returned in the response for an asynchronous call. Whose value is not set when it is created. When the value is set, it calls the function passed to the `.then` handler.

A promise can be in three states.

1. Pending State -> when it is just a proxy object without any value
2. Fulfilled State -> when it has a value to be returned which can be handled using `.then` handler
3. Rejected State -> when it has an error to be returned which can be handled using `.catch` handler